# Generate XML - Exclude nodes

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Please see the SQL below:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select incident_id FROM INCIDENTS where incident_id=600') xml
from dual
```

It returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <INCIDENT_ID>600</INCIDENT_ID>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

How can I exclude return this:

```
<SYSTEM URN="114644">
<INCIDENT_ID>600</INCIDENT_ID>
<SYSTEM>
```

I want to hardcode the first row and the third row of the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extract function to get your desired output

```
EXTRACT (XML) is similar to the EXISTSNODE function. 
It applies a VARCHAR2 XPath string and returns an XMLType instance containing an XML fragment. You can specify an absolute XPath_string with an initial slash or a relative XPath_string by omitting the initial slash. 
If you omit the initial slash, the context of the relative path defaults to the root node...
```

also see similar question here
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1126429?tstart=0

Comment: I have edited the question.  Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: So you can concatenate the hard coded string something like  [ SELECT '<SYSTEM URN="114644">' ||  OTHER XML parts here || '</SYSTEM>' FROM XYZ...]